# Procedure to migrate a question to another stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

So I've been eagerly waiting for an answer to my question: [Solving the quantum an-harmonic oscillator pertubatively?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207766/)

Yet, for some reason I haven't got it ... What is the general procedure to transfer a question to another stackexchange like Math-stackexchange (after my bounty expires)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general procedure for getting your question migrated to another stack exchange site is to flag it yourself, with a custom flag explaining the situation. The moderators will typically oblige (**disclaimer**: These flags are handled on a case-by-case basis, so the moderators will assess if your request is reasonable before acting).